# SqlCeDataReader Read() returning false

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I am working on a card game which uses a database to store and retrieve cards. Unfortunately I am having trouble retrieving data from the database.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CardGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Card c = new Card();
            Card d;

            c.Name = "TestCard";
            c.Pack = "Pack";
            c.Value = 5;
            c.Color = Colors.green;
            c.Description = "Describing stuff";

            //Database.CreateCardTable(); (Already created)
            Database.InsertCard(c);
            d = Database.RetrieveCard("TestCard");

            Console.WriteLine(d.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Database.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CardGame
{
    class Database
    {
        public static void CreateCardTable()
        {
            string sqlStr;
            SqlCeConnection CardConn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CardsConnectionString);

            sqlStr = "CREATE TABLE Data " +
                "(Name NVARCHAR(50), " +
                "Pack NVARCHAR(50), " +
                "Value INT, " +
                "Color INT," +
                "Description NVARCHAR(200))";

            SqlCeCommand CardComm = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStr, CardConn);

            try
            {
                CardConn.Open();
                CardComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Tables Created Successfully!");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Error creating tables.");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (CardConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    CardConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void InsertCard(Card c)
        {
            SqlCeConnection CardConn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CardsConnectionString);

            try
            {
                CardConn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand insertCommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Data VALUES(@Name, @Pack, @Value, @Color, @Description)", CardConn);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", c.Name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Pack", c.Pack);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Value", c.Value);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Color", c.Color);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Description", c.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Card inserted successfully");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some kind of error.");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (CardConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    CardConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public static Card RetrieveCard(string name)
        {
            Card c = new Card();
            SqlCeConnection CardConn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CardsConnectionString);

            try
            {
                CardConn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand retrieveCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name=@Name", CardConn);
                retrieveCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", name);
                SqlCeDataReader reader = retrieveCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reader: " + reader["Name"].ToString());
                    c.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                    //read rest
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }


            return c;
        }

        public void CreateAccountDB(string DBName)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I run insert card I do get a success message (at the end of the try statement). When I do `Database.RetrieveCard("TestCard");` it reaches the line `while (reader.Read())` but my program does not reach the code inside of the while statement. How can I fix my code so that I can read cards from the database?

Comment: Can u verify that query returns data?

Answer (score 0):

I built the command to insert a card into the database but I never actually executed it. So nothing was ever inserted so when I go to retrieve the card it will return nothing because there is nothing in the database!

I changed

```
try
            {
                CardConn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand insertCommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Data VALUES(@Name, @Pack, @Value, @Color, @Description)", CardConn);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", c.Name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Pack", c.Pack);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Value", c.Value);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Color", c.Color);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Description", c.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Card inserted successfully");
            }
```

to

```
try
            {
                CardConn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand insertCommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Data VALUES(@Name, @Pack, @Value, @Color, @Description)", CardConn);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", c.Name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Pack", c.Pack);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Value", (int)c.Value);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Color", (int)c.Color);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Description", c.Description);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Card inserted successfully");
            }
```